# Min number of colors for shared light switches

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle

I recently moved to a new house, and this house has more light switches than I'm used to.

There a **N** lights in the house and **M** switches where **N < M**.

*A light may be controlled by 1 or more light switches*.

If a light is controlled by *more than one* switch, then we'll say the set of switches which control that light are *shared*.

The reason for the sharing of switches is so that you can walk from one from to the next without needing to turn off the light while you are still in the room. But I keep forgetting which switches are shared, so I proposed to label them such that every switch that shares a light will have the same label.

Of course I could assign every light in the house a unique label, but I would like to use the fewest unique labels necessary.

Given a set of rooms, switches and their relationships, what is the *smallest* number of unique labels I will need such that no switch in a room shares a label unless they also share a light?

I should clarify that I actually did move recently and ran into problems with light switches which made me start thinking of this more general problem and I'm trying to find out how I would go about formalizing the problem and then finding a general solution for any house.

Comment: At first I though the four color theorem might be applicable but I don't think it is because you can have an arbitrary number of switches in a given room.

Comment: If your only requirement is to “label them with little color stickers such that every switch that shares a light will have the same color label,” use the same color for every switch. Then you are assured that every switch that [any condition at all] will have the same color label, because all the labels are the same color, and any group of switches have the same color label.

Comment: @SteveKass I mentioned this in the question already. Yes you can use one color per light, but you can also use less. The question is about the minimum number of colors required. Edit: I see what you meant. I need to make my question more precise but I'm having trouble verbalizing the constraint. Edit2: Updated the question to be more precise, hope the wording makes sense.

Comment: I suggested you use one color, period, not one color per switch, so the minimum number of colors required is $1$. I see you have restated the requirement now, so additional colors are required if within a single room there are switches controlling different lights. With no information beyond the fact that there are $N$ lights and $M$ switches, with $M>N$, you could still have, say, $N$ rooms, and within a single room, all the switches in the room control the light in that room. Then you can still make due with just $1$ color. The question seems poorly-defined without more information.

Comment: Are the switches that control a given light guaranteed to be XOR'd?  This makes sense because you can change the state of the light from any one, regardless of where the others are. The  "in a room" phrase is very important.  The mathematical problem is given N lights and M switches, where each light is controlled by the XOR of a subset of the switches how do we label the switches to indicate the lights they control?  The twist is that you are willing to reuse labels between the rooms.  I don't have an answer, I just think I am helping to state the problem precisely.

Comment: So when you say "  you can walk from one room to the other and turn off a light from either room ". Does that mean you have light switches in one room that control a light in a different room.

Comment: You very well could need one color for each light. Just imagine one room with $N$ switches, each corresponding to a different light. The question needs more restrictions for any better bound than this.

Comment: @Peter Yes. Perhaps it would be useful to further restrict it to only adjacent rooms. That is, a room on one side of the house will not control the light to a room far off on the other side of the house.

Comment: @bburGsamohT yeah, as SteveKass mentioned, there is a trivial case where you have just a single room. I'm having trouble defining the problem properly. I wasn't trying to come up with a puzzle, I really do have lots of light switches and am trying to figure out how to label them =) I'm starting to think maybe this was the wrong stackexchange to post this to. I think what I really want is an *algorithm* that given a set of rooms, switches and relationships between switches would provide an optimal placement of color labels.

Comment: I think that in order to solve this, we're going to need more variables, such as the greatest number of switches in one room, and the greatest number of switches for one light. We also need to know what constraints there are on switch placement - can a switch exist that controls a light in a nonadjacent room, or in an adjacent room that is not directly connected, e.g., two bedrooms, where you must use the hallway to get from one to the other. And (not sure if this matters, but,) are there any loops? For example, a bathroom between two bedrooms but no direct access to the hallway.

Comment: In any case, you definitely need *at least* as many labels as the greatest number of lights controllable from within a single room.

Answer (score 0):

In actual fact you could use just one colour, and shape the stickers with a pair of scissors ( square, triangle circle, etc.)  according to which light the switch belongs to. But this may not be in the spirit of the problem.

If you are asking this for a purely practical reason, then personally ,I would have all the switches that control the light in one room the same colour. If there is more than one light in a room I would still have the same colour for the switches but different shaped stickers for the different lights. And I would pick a colour according to a significantly coloured item in the room that is obvious, thereby making it easy to remember.

Comment: There's definitely a practical aspect to this, I really am trying to label my light switches, but the practical problem made me think more generally about the problem of how many unique "labels" I would need which is really what I am trying to solve. Shaping the stickers is basically equivalent to using a new "label". In my example I used colors but it might be better if I had said "unique identifier" instead of color.